# Logging long JSON gets trimmed in azure application insights

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, azure-application-insights

My goal is to log the users requests by using the azure application insights, the requests are being converted into JSON format and then saved.

Sometimes the user request can be very long and it gets trimmed in the azure application insight view which result in not-valid JSON.

Underneath `CustomDimensions` it looks like:

[image: trimmed json]

I'm using the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient` namespace.

This is my code:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "RequestJSON", requestJSON }
};
TelemetryClientInstance.TrackTrace("some description", SeverityLevel.Verbose, properties);
```

I'm refer this overload:

```
public void TrackTrace(string message, SeverityLevel severityLevel, IDictionary<string, string> properties);
```

Comment: For custom property, the max value length is 8192. If that's the case, you should consider other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [Trace telemetry: Application Insights data model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-trace-telemetry), for [Custom Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-trace-telemetry#custom-properties), the **Max value length is 8192**.

In your case, it exceeds the limitation.

I can think of 2 solutions:

1.Write the requestJSON into **message** field when using `TrackTrace` method. The [trace message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/data-model-trace-telemetry#message) `Max length is 32768 characters`, it may meet your need.

2.Split the requestJSON  into more than 1 custom properties, when it's length is larger than 8192. For example, if the length of the requestJSON is 2*8192, then you can add 2 custome properties: `property RequestJSON_1` stores the first 8192 data, and `property RequestJSON_2` stores the left 8192 data.

When using solution 2, you can easily use `Kusto query` to join `property RequestJSON_1` and `property RequestJSON_2` together, so you get the completed  / valid json data.